# Redirect network from vm1 to vm2 using IPtables

Tags: iptables, virtualbox

I want to redirect all network traffic from VirtualBox vm1 to vm2 using IPtables. Not all the applications in vm1 are proxy friendly.

How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. To make it more easier for contributors to help you, please add some more details on the exact configuration you are using (e.g. host and guest OS, SW version etc.)

Comment: Are you looking to redirect all _new_ connections to vm2?

Comment: Like Whonix, redirecting all from Workstation to Gateway without setting proxy to software in Workstation, but I own other faster proxy not Tor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want all traffic from VM1 to be routed through VM2. If that is correct, you can try the following:

- VM1 = 10.20.20.10/24 (**eth0**)
- VM2 = 10.20.20.20/24 (**eth0**) and 192.168.20.10 (**eth1**)

Since VM2 is also attached to a NAT adapter via **eth1**, its default gateway will be something like **192.168.20.1**

Configure VM1 with a single NIC (eth0) that will be attached to host-only adapter

Configure VM2 with 2 NICs (eth0 and eth1), one attached to the same host-only adapter as VM1, and the other attached to the NAT adapter (for internet access)

Enable ip_forwarding on VM2

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Also use iptables to enable masquerading on VM2

`/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE`

`/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`
`/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT`

Then set VM1's default gateway, to point to VM2

`ip route add default via 10.20.20.20`

If you are happy with the results, consider making these changes persistent.